# How do I add a ferry route to Google Maps?

Tags: ferries, maps

There is a ferry near me that is not in Google Maps.  How do I add it as a suggestion to Google?

Comment: This probably belongs on the [Web Applications SE site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but I've upvoted it because I think it's a good question.

Comment: Can it be moved there, or do I have to repost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had some success with reporting problems on Google maps, such as missing connections between roads.  It may take a few weeks but there appears to be some form of human review.  They keep changing things but at the time of writing, in the desktop view, there's a "send feedback" menu item.  None of the options are perfect, but one is to report a missing road.

Comment: Speaking as someone who used to work on exactly this part of Google Maps a number of years ago, this is correct.  Ferries are probably tricky and won't go through the normal moderation flow, so it may take some time to get through, if it does at all.  Still, it's the best option the general public has.

Comment: I did use this method, and appreciate your reassurance that it is correct.